# machine learning project ideas

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, machine-learning

I am interested about playing with machine learning algorithm and time series analysis. Is there website/resource with a comprehensive list of sample projects/proposals one may be interested about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to read this and look at the two terms of projects and additional projects.

Enjoy!

http://blog.smellthedata.com/2010/07/choosing-first-machine-learning-project.html

Answer (score 5):

You may want to have a look at the proceedings of prominent machine learning conferences such as Intl. Conference on Machine Learning (ICML) and Adv. in Neural Information Processing Systems (NIPS). This will give you a fair idea of interesting relevant problems currently being tackled in ML.

Answer (score 1):

Consider some of the following project ideas:

- Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) sampling of mutli-modal distribution
- EM Algorithm for Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) and Hidden Markov Model (HMM)
- Time-series analysis using HMM, ARIMA models, Kalman Filter
- Time-series prediction using LSTM recurrent neural network with Keras
- Topic Modeling with LDA and online HDP

For reference implementations have a look at: https://github.com/vsmolyakov/ml
and https://github.com/vsmolyakov/experiments_with_python

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://github.com/cuge1995/awesome-time-series. Btw, if you are interested in the XXX area, go to Github and search "awesome_XXX" can always help.